# How to validate a form input containing only space character(s) in PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am validating a form for my website (still on local server). I used help from w3schools.com mostly. But I noticed that my form accepts an input if the user enters 1 or more space characters.

I know the trim() function remove space from beginning and end of the data and that works fine. But I what a case where a user input only one or more empty whitespace character the php validation will return it as an empty field.

Below a piece of my code:

```
function sanitize($input){
    $input = trim($input);
    $input = stripcslashes($input);
    $input = htmlspecialchars($input);
    return $input;
}
//Full Name Validation
//if field is empty and contains only whitespace
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if (empty($_POST["fname"])){
        $fname_err = "Cannot be empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nick you need `sanitize($_POST["fname"]) === ''` in your if statement, conceptually your advice is correct though.

Comment: @JoshRumbut oops! That was careless of me. I'll re-comment.

Comment: You're not actually calling your `sanitize` function. Try changing `if (empty($_POST["fname"])){` to `if (empty($_POST["fname"]) || sanitize($_POST["fname"]) == ''){`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ctype_space function. It returns true if all of the characters in a string create white space: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php

Try updating your second if statement to also perform the ctype_space check:

```
//Full Name Validation
//if field is empty and contains only whitespace
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if (empty($_POST["fname"]) || ctype_space($_POST["fname"])){
        $fname_err = "Cannot be empty";
    }
}
```

Also, remember to actually call your sanitize function.